# Oracle PL/SQL > Stored Procedure Hanging Indefinitely

Tags: oracle, stored-procedures, plsql, oracle11g, stored-functions

I'm in the business side of the house and do not have full DBA privileges to our Oracle 11g database. I have the privileges necessary to build and run stored procedures and I have one that is hanging indefinitely.

We're developing a new system and have several life-cycles. My code works 100% fine in an earlier lifecycle (call it AD) and hangs indefinitely in the next lifecyle (QA). It stops at the first major SQL pull and never returns.

When I run the exact SQL that's inside the stored procedure outside as a straight SQL pull, it comes back in 2.6 seconds (using the same input parameters and the same QA lifecyle server).

I have limited ability to see what's going on inside the stored procedure as it's running because of my privileges and my DBAs don't have any insight into PL/SQL code to help debug or troubleshoot.

So, my open-ended question is: what could be going wrong?? I know this is vague. Things I have checked:

- The database has the data in the tables I'm pulling from
- I've checked that all of my input parameters are good and that they are being passed from procedure to function, etc. correctly
- I've run the same code outside of the procedure and it returns quickly and displays the correct data.
- The exact code works in a lower lifecycle (literally just copy/pasted it from AD to QA).
- The DBA says the server environment is exactly the same (I'm not sure I believe him, but have no direct means to verify).

Any help you can provide would be golden. I could post the code, but its about 2-3K in length, so I'm not sure that's helpful. Give the code works fine and was copy/pasted as-is, I don't think it's a coding problem, but system/environmental problem.

Any ideas would be helpful.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: As it is, this is probably unanswerable because it is too broad-- there are too many possible problems.  How do you know that the code "stops at the first major SQL pull"?  Do you have privileges to see what your code is waiting on (can you at least query `v$session`)?  Can you enlist the DBA to help you diagnose what your code is waiting on?  Are you sure that the code you are running outside the procedure is actually the same-- are you using literals outside the procedure, for example, and bind variables inside?

Comment: When I self-terminate the proc, it stops at the same line item, the start of the first major SQL pull. I don't have privs to see what it's waiting on and am trying to get debug privs from our DBA so I can see more (there's some interdepartmental BS going on there). I'm double checking the SQL outside the proc against the SQL inside the proc and trying to narrow down where it fails. I'm checking the literals as you've stated again...I checked them before, but maybe I missed something. I know it's super broad...Even if I can get ideas on what to ask my DBA to check, that's helpful.

Comment: you can get plenty of information here on S.O. about debugging Oracle by searching for `[oracle] v\$session` (you need to escape the `$` char). Good luck.

Comment: @rfcmonarch - have the DBA check for any locks which are blocking the session in which your code is running.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like this issue was  unrelated to the stored procedure. Thanks for all the comments. :)